# How Can I Put Buttons After Text?

Tags: ios, xamarin, cross-platform

```
UIRelativeLayout content = new UIRelativeLayout();

cell.AddSubview(content);

content.Frame = cell.Bounds;

content.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All;

content.GetLayoutParams().AddLayoutRule(LayoutRule.CenterInParent);

//content.LayoutMargins = new UIEdgeInsets(5, 5, 5, 5);


// make a UITableViewCell with a clickable button

cell.TextLabel.Text = model.Button.Description;



UIButton button = new UIButton();

button.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Orange;
                button.GetLayoutParams().AddLayoutRule(LayoutRule.CenterInParent);

button.GetLayoutParams().AddLayoutRule(LayoutRule.RightOf, content);

button.GetLayoutParams().Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(LayoutParams.UNSPECIFIED, LayoutParams.UNSPECIFIED, 25, 25);

//debug.GetLayoutParams().AddLayoutRule(LayoutRule.RightOf, _view);


button.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) =>

{

 model.Button.OnClick.Execute(null);

};



content.AddSubview(button);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
view.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(view.Frame.Y, pos.Y, view.Frame.Width, view.Frame.Height);
```

Use:

```
view.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(pos.X, view.Frame.Y, view.Frame.Width, view.Frame.Height);
```

FYI:

Your swipe up/down seems like it should be using `Frame.X` vs. `Frame.Y` unless you are trying to perform a diagonal move of the `UIView`:

```
view.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(view.Frame.X, pos.Y, view.Frame.Width, view.Frame.Height);
```